# How does $(k+1)!(k+2)-1 = (k+2)!-1$?

Tags: induction, factorial

I'm trying to do a proof by induction question and I'm at the very last part.
Apparently $(k+1)!(k+2)-1 = (k+2)!-1$. I have checked using an online calculator.

I don't understand why though.

Comment: Cancel $-1$ and you find the result immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recurrence for $n!$ is $n! = n (n-1)!.$ Apply for $n=k+2.$

Comment: Yep, got it! Thanks!